# Magento 2 add custom tab to account dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin, tabs

I want to add a custom tab on account dashboard in Magento2 and I have seen many tutorials for creating new module but not one showing exact location for placing that module.

Right now I have placed my custom module on this path `app/code` folder but it is not working.

I have followed this tutorial for creating a new module,

https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-tab-in-customer-account-section-magento-2/#comment-5094

Anyone can help to know the exact location for placing module.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if its helpful for you or not

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps listed below :

Add below files into your custom extension.

**Ex:-  => Namespace:- ABC => modulename : Myblog**

=> Create **customer_account.xml** into `ABC/Myblog/view/frontend/layout`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-myblog">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">myblog/customer/index</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"> My Blog</argument>
            </arguments>
         </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

=> Create **myblog_customer_index.xml** into `ABC/Myblog/view/frontend/layout`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<update handle="customer_account"/> 
<body> 
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title"> 
            <action method="setPageTitle"> 
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Blog</argument> 
            </action> 
     </referenceBlock> 
     <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_email" template="ABC_Myblog::myblog.phtml"> 
        </block> 
    </referenceContainer> 
</body> 
</page>
```

=> Create **Index.php** into `ABC/Myblog/Controller/Customer`

```
<?php 
namespace ABC\Myblog\Controller\Customer;  
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action { 

 public function execute() { 

    $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
    $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
  } 

} 
?>
```

=> Create **myblog.phtml** into `ABC/Myblog/view/frontend/templates`

```
<?php 
 // Add Some Code Here  
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your code , but i have created same type of code and added module on app/code directory but nothing showing on frontend

Comment: remove var and generated folder...and try it.

Comment: ok what is ABC in this ? where i need to add this after create? in app/code folder ?

Comment: Its like app/code/ABC/Myblog

Comment: Create ABC folder into app/code and then Create Myblog folder into app/code/ABC folder

Comment: my bad luck nothing showing on tab listing of dashboard

Comment: can you tell me...any system.log or exception.log generated or not..? what type of error display...?

Comment: no error showing related of module, even i wrote wrong code in index.php still no effect on site.

Comment: Then, check your magento path and fronturl is correct or not.

Comment: where i need to check magento path ?

Answer (score 1):

so finally I have created the module for add new tab. if anybody wants then download from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/23yt71gdh8xdbv9/Privacy.zip?dl=0 and activate module with the command

```
php bin/magento module:enable Privacy_Policy
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your module to app/code.
After that run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` and `php bin/magento cache:flush` from CLI.

Comment: i have run same command from putty , but still nothing showing on frontend

Comment: Try running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and php bin/magento cache:flush as well

Comment: after running these command my paid paid plugin start showing in admin but custom module still not showing, is this right location app/code for place module ?

Comment: Yes, the location is correct. Kindly share your code, may be there is some issue in the code.

Comment: 1. as i already mentioned, i have follow https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-tab-in-customer-account-section-magento-2/#comment-5094 article  and created module , i have not done any changes yet in article code.

2. i need to call this module anywhere ? or it should auto work after uploading ?

Answer (score 0):

I often use a skeleton I get from here:

https://mage2gen.com/

Which takes out a lot of the grunt and setup work (be sure to verify whether everything in `registration.php` and such is accurate).

Magento modules have a Vendor name and a Module name. For example, my company is called Company, and I made a module to handle pricelists of our catalog, so the module is called Pricelist.

My module is placed so the file path looks like `app/code/Company/Pricelist/...(module files)`

After putting the files correctly, run (with the same folder that contains the app folder as the working directory) `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. If you log in as admin, you'll be able to see your new module under `Stores/Configuration/Advanced/Admin`. It should show as enabled.

In the same folder, now run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`